# JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() method in Golang

Tags: javascript, time, go, utc

In JavaScript we can use this method to get the offset zone.

```
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;

}
```

For example , if we are in Berlin , Germany we return -120 minutes. If we are in London we have -60 minutes.

I need exactly that method in golang. Exists??? Thanks to every one.

Answer (score 1):

The `time.Time` type has what you're looking for:

```
zone, offset := time.Now().Zone()
```

`zone` the the timezone name, and offset is its UTC offset. Pretty simple

Example on the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Ij-TuuRX_K